# How to solve the following differential equation of the form $\frac{k}{2}\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^{2}}-f+f^{3}=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the ordinary differential equation
$$
\frac{k}{2}\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^{2}}-f+f^{3}=0
$$

with $f(x=0)=0$ and $f'(x=0)=0$

Comment: $W|A$ gives horrendous solutions: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(k%2F2)f%27%27-f(x)%2Bf%5E3%3D0

Comment: The standard trick is to multiply by $\frac{df}{dx}$ and integrate. We will get a separable differential equation. We will I think need an additional initial condition, most simply $f'(0)$, to complete the calculation.

Comment: Also, the initial conditions are insufficient to get a unique solution. Are you sure this is not a first order ode (replacing $f''$ with $f'$). This also gives a much simpler [solution on wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(k%2F2)f%27-f(x)%2Bf%5E3%3D0)

Comment: The "trick" unfortunately leads to a difficult partial fractions integration, which will only be feasible for a very carefully chosen $f'(0)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas $f'(x=0)=0$

Comment: I think, with these initial values, $f\equiv 0$ is the solution of the problem!

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{k}{2}f''-f+f^3=0$$
with conditions : $f(0)=f'(0)=0$

$$f''(0)=\frac{2}{k}(f(0)-f(0)^3)=0$$
$\frac{k}{2}f'''-f'+3f^2f'=0$
$$f'''(0)=\frac{2}{k}(f'(0)-3f(0)^2f'(0))=0$$
And so on... By induction, all the successive derivatives are $=0$.

This draw to expect the solution $f(x)=0$.

Of course, in case of initial conditions different from $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ the result would not be so trivial.